# Name of Googles Syntax Highlighting

Tags: chrome, chrome-os

I wondered what the name of googles syntax highlighting is, that they use on their googlesource.com page and for example [Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/+/trunk/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), [prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) might be a candidate.

And [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-code-prettify/) it says

> Powers code.google.com and stackoverflow.com

However if I look at the Chromium site, it mentions [gitiles](https://github.com/google/gitiles/blob/master/Documentation/markdown.md),
But I fail to spot more than a

> `import syntaxhighlight.ParseResult;`

In the code. It might be the Java port of prettify: [java-prettify](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-prettify/)

**Update:**

The [COPYING](https://github.com/google/gitiles/blob/master/COPYING) file lists prettify.

**Update:**

The [WORKSPACE](https://github.com/google/gitiles/blob/master/WORKSPACE) file lists java-prettify.

> `artifact = "com.github.twalcari:java-prettify:1.2.2",`